# when link is clicked .. I want to move from ( view controlle1 ==>uiwebview1 ) to (VC2 ==>uiwebview2) to show that link (XCODE)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, uiwebview

it's been almost a week of reading and trying all of these different solutions from this website and others .. but unfortunately nothing work ..

I'm trying to develop a News app (basically, main page and Details page) .. I want to use two different uiwebviews in two view controllers .. For example: The FirstView includes the First uiwebview .. and this uiwebview shows the page (index.htm ) which includes many different news (links).. when the user click on any link ( e.g. details.htm?Id=..) it shows that link in the Second uiwebview in the SecondView controller ...

what I need exactly is, when user click on a link on uiwebview1, it directly open the view controller2 (SecondView) and open that link on the webview2 ... I know it's by using shouldStartLoadWithRequest as ive seen many ( if not all ) examples of how to use it .. but it never worked with me .. the second view controller can never be shown ..as I also set the delegate = self ..

I really tried to do it, but as i'm **new ios developer** .. I really need some help to get this done ... and i would really appreciate more if someone gives me a link to download the example, not because of anything, but I sometimes find it difficult to put the code on the right place ...and this is might me my problem ...

Many thanks ...

=========
I found this solution on [Within a (BOOL)webView: How to open a URL clicked in UIWebView that opens a Modal UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10052264/within-a-boolwebview-how-to-open-a-url-clicked-in-uiwebview-that-opens-a-moda)

and after much work .. all errors disappeared .. but still cant move the second view controller .. it never shown .. I used this code :
this is in the viewcontroller.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

//- (IBAction)prepareForSegue;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL *url;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL *targetUrl;
```

and this is on the viewcontroller.m

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
//Gets the link.
if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
NSURL *URL = [request URL];
NSLog(@"url:%@",request); //Get's the url itself
//        [self.navigationController pushViewController:SecondView animated:YES];
//        [secondView release];
self.webView.delegate = self;
//        ViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondView"];
//        [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
//
if ([[URL scheme] isEqualToString:@"http"] ||
[[URL scheme] isEqualToString: @"https" ])  {
targetUrl = url;
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SecondView" sender:self];
return NO;
}
return YES;
}
return YES;   
}
```

and before that

```
@synthesize webView;
@synthesize targetUrl;
@synthesize url;
```

and finally :

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Source Controller = %@", [segue sourceViewController]);
    NSLog(@"Destination Controller = %@", [segue destinationViewController]);
    NSLog(@"Segue Identifier = %@", [segue identifier]);

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SecondView"]) {

        ViewController *wVC = [segue destinationViewController];
        wVC.url = targetUrl ; // replace article.url with your url.
    }

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSURL *urla= [NSURL URLWithString:@"Index.htm"]; NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urla]; [webView loadRequest:requestURL];
//
```

I exactly copied the code above in my project .. and I believe there is a very tiny mistake ... it doesn't show my SecondView at all when I click on links from index.htm... what should I change on that code ...

Many thanks ...

Comment: Does your `prepareForSegue:` method get called?  (That is, do you see those `NSLog()` results?)

Comment: Hi sir, thanks for your reply .. it really shows nothing in in the NSLog .. could you please download my entire project n tell me where is the mistake (Abroadtostudy.com/WebAPP.zip)  I uploaded it on my own website ... I really appreciate your help @PhillipMills

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you don't have any segue defined in your storyboard.  If you connect your two view controllers with a segue, name it "SecondView", and uncomment the following line...

`self.webView.delegate = self;`

...you'll get past your current problem.

(When the second controller displays, it doesn't seem to load the new URL...but that's some different problem.)

Comment: hi sir, the segue only worked when i use a button ... it doesn't work when I click on a link from the webview .. dunno how to do it in the right way .. this is the most important thing .. we ( or I :( ) could work on the other issue after fixing this, which took more than a week now ... I would really appreciate it sir if you download and fix the issue from the link above from my previous reply .. @Phillip Mills

Comment: I did that before I answered you.  Make sure you uncomment the line that sets the delegate.  Check that `shouldStartLoadWithRequest:` is being called.  If not, then the delegate is wrong.

Comment: thanks sir for your reply .. still didn't work ... I know that you've downloaded the file .. but I actually meant that if you please could edit that issue for me and upload the file again .. I may know the missing point that I couldn't sort out for a week ..seems like it's not a code that I could someone could give it to me, is to do with the segue and its staff :( .. if you please could do this, I really would appreciate it ..